# Java 8 convert a List<Object> to Map<K,V> using the fields of the object's children?

Tags: java, java-stream

The situation is simple: I have a list of object `List<ParentClass> list`
and would like to convert it to `Map<orderKey, price>`

The class looks like the following

```
class ParentClass{
   Child1Class a;
   Child2Class b;
}
```

The orderKey class looks like this

```
class orderKey{
   String id;
   String itemName;
}
```

The children classes look like this

```
class Child1Class{
   String id;
   String itemName;
   Date date;
   .....
}

class Child2Class{
   BigDecimal price;
   ....
}
```

All of the classes have corresponded getters and setters for each field. So I essentially want to map the fields of the children's fields. How can I do this?

```
-----------------------------MY ATTEMPT IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS--------------------------------------
list.stream().
.collect(Collectors
.toMap(ParentClass::getA, ParentClass::getB)
.entrySet().stream()
......
then I'm stuck
```

Not sure how I can construct the temp object `orderKey` as the key for the new map. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate the `orderKey` inside the first function reference passed in `toMap` ? Instead of `ParentClass::getA` you would write something like `parent -> new orderKey(...);`. You would also drop the `entrySet().stream()` then

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this.  Since you didn't provide getters I had to access the fields.  It also presumes an `OrderKey` constructor.

```
Map<OrderKey,BigDecimal> map = list
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors
                         .toMap(parent ->
                             new OrderKey(parent.a.id,
                                  parent.a.itemName),
                          parent->parent.b.price));
```

With `getters`, it would look like this.

```
    Map<OrderKey,BigDecimal> map=   
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                .toMap(parent ->
                      new OrderKey(parent.getA().getId(),
                                   parent.getA().getItemName()),
                       parent->parent.getB().getPrice()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<K, V> map = list.stream().
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     parent -> {
                       // the key in the map is of type orderKey, instantiate it here, you have "parent" which is one element of the list.
                       return new orderKey(...);
                     }, 
                     ParentClass::getB
                  ));
```